Autodesk Platform Services users/import not working for me
I'm trying to add users to ACC projects using Workato.
I keep getting the error:
code: 2000,
message: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
Any help would be welcome.....Many thank sin advance
The endpoint I'm calling is:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v2/regions/eu/accounts/ff3df945-6b20-405e-938e-12a7ba781972/projects/a8c648de-2eab-4048-90fd-681423d9a5c0/users/import
(according to the documentation I shouldn't us the b. prefix with account and project id).
I'm passing the following data:
Data:
{
Array:
[
{
Email: lomans-acc-sa@lomansgroep.nl,
Services:
{
Project administration:
{
Access level: admin
},
Document management:
{
Access level: admin
}
},
Industry roles:
[
ced2b921-5349-48fe-a3d7-50608257f469
],
Company ID: 82b2409a-e9a4-4040-96c6-8453f02d74bf
}
]
}
},
Request headers:
[
{
name: Content-Type,
value: application/json
},
{
name: region,
value: EMEA
}
]
}
The reply I'm getting is:
{
failure: 1,
success: 0,
success_items: [],
failure_items:
[
{
email: lomans-acc-sa@lomansgroep.nl,
services:
{
project_administration:
{
access_level: admin
},
document_management:
{
access_level: admin
}
},
company_id: 82b2409a-e9a4-4040-96c6-8453f02d74bf,
industry_roles:
[
ced2b921-5349-48fe-a3d7-50608257f469
],
first_name: Bas,
last_name: Spaan,
errors:
[
{
code: 2000,
message: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
}
],
project_id: a8c648de-2eab-4048-90fd-681423d9a5c0,
account_id: ff3df945-6b20-405e-938e-12a7ba781972
}
]
}

Are you using this endpoint for ACC project? This endpoint only works for BIM 360 project.

Indeed that was the issue. Thanks mate. It was working in April when we tested on the US server, so I dis't check. And i deed in the test it's also not working. Changed it and it's resolved

Cool, happy to hear.

They endpoint you are using only works for BIM 360 projects, it's not compatible with ACC.
